# -webkit-user-select: none; - not working

Tags: html, css, ipad, mobile

I'm creating a site that will be viewed on the iPad and I'm trying to prevent the copy and paste bubble from appearing when the user touches and holds on an image because I'd like something to happen ontouchstart and ontouchend.

Here is my html

```
<img class="appImg" src="img/fundMobile.jpg" />
```

Here is my css

```
.appImg{        
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

Once I press and hold on my iPad the bubble still appears. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try including `e.preventDefault()` in the `ontouchstart` handler:

```
yourElement.ontouchstart = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: This is 100% true. I just tested with iPad and iOS 14.8.  These alone don't work: `touch-action: none;` or `-webkit-user-select: none;` or `user-select: none;`. Only thing that prevented the "hold and press" selection is handling `touchstart`. Side note, handling `pointerdown` does not work, only `touchstart`.

Answer (score 0):

Your css is correct but, your css may still be cached, this is something I noticed a bit with iOS 6 UIWebViews, add a url parameter to your link that should fix it after a refresh.

```
<link href="styles.css?cache=123" rel="stylesheet" />
```