# Firefox image selecting bug CSS

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am working on project and added images as relative positions. But in browsers images are working fine except Firefox. When i click image it selects the image. You can see by visit this link :

Visit : http://tinypic.com/r/5e7go1/8

or you can check website URL : http://cqindia.org/website/ here i uploaded the website.

When you open this website in firefox and scroll down to slider section then you can see the bug.

Main problem is when i click background image i select the image.

I have already tried too many things : Like - positions to absolute and changed z-index but nothing work.

Also i have visited some stack pages but no answer found.

Already used this css code :

```
.main_container section img {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This is because the images are in html only with `<img>` tag. Cant you call them via CSS ?

Comment: No i can't, because project is finished and this is only problem left and i can't understand why only firefox giving this problem.

Comment: If i put <img> tag inside div tag will it work then ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [-webkit-user-select: none; - not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613503/webkit-user-select-none-not-working)

Comment: Check your CSS, the live site doesn't have any mention of `user-select`. I added it manually with Firebug and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks, Maybe as you said it's duplicate issue with webkit.. Thanks bro it was very helpful :)

Answer (score 4):

Try disabling user selecting on that image:

```
 -moz-user-select: none;
```

If that works, all browsers can be addressed via:

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

Comment: I don't see your rule for `.main_container section img` on the website (URL you gave above), but quick placing it via firebug removes the selection just fine.